# R problem: some dawn/dusk calculations give NA, some give actual values

Tags: r, na, date-sunrise

I am trying to determine if date/times are during dawn, dusk, night, or day. I am using the maptools library's sunriset() and crepuscule() functions. 
All of the sunrise and sunset calculations are working, but when I have it do dawn/dusk, I get NA's for some of the calculations, while for others it gives me the time of dawn/dusk. 
Anyone have any ideas?

I've posted some reproducible example of my code below. Note, there doesn't seem to be a particular year, or date that this happens for!

```
library(lubridate) 
library(maptools) 
library(sp)



# Build example data set to show issues with dawn/dusk calculations; 
df <- data.frame(Lon=c(-136.1740, -136.1683, -136.1670, -136.1683, -136.1775, -136.1913, -136.2070, -137.7000, -137.7022, -137.7232, -137.7332, -137.7390, -137.7434, -137.7483, -137.7554, -136.0803, -136.0835), Lat=c(57.03300, 57.08083, 57.09700, 57.13115, 57.15701, 57.17111, 57.17961, 57.84775, 57.84896, 57.85831, 57.85919, 57.85680, 57.85320, 57.84934, 57.84586, 56.90012, 56.90763), date.time=ymd_hms("2007-07-08 09:00:00", "2007-07-08 10:00:00", "2007-07-08 11:00:00", "2007-07-08 12:00:00", "2007-07-08 13:00:00", "2007-07-09 14:00:00", "2007-07-09 15:00:00", "2009-07-30 04:00:00", "2009-07-30 05:00:00", "2009-07-30 06:00:00", "2009-07-30 07:00:00", "2009-07-30 08:00:00", "2009-07-30 09:00:00", "2009-07-30 10:00:00", "2009-07-30 11:00:00","2007-07-18 06:00:00","2007-07-18 07:00:00"))

#Make a new column for local date/time (Alaska time):
df$date.time.local <- as.POSIXct(df$date.time, tz="GMT", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df$date.time.local<- format(df$date.time.local, tz="us/alaska") 
df$date.time.local <- as.POSIXct(df$date.time.local, tz="us/alaska",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
head(df)

#Create vector of locations in Spatial Points format: 
stcalc<-subset(df, select=c("Lon","Lat"))
stcalc <- SpatialPoints(stcalc, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
head(stcalc@coords)

#Create vector of local date/time & use it to calculate sunrise & sunset
dt_local <- as.POSIXct(df$date.time, tz="GMT", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dt_local<- format(dt_local, tz="us/alaska") 
dt_local <- as.POSIXct(dt_local, tz="us/alaska",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
head(dt_local)

#Calculate sunrise and sunset using local time
sr<-sunriset(stcalc, dt_local, direction = "sunrise", POSIXct.out = TRUE)
st<-sunriset(stcalc, dt_local, direction="sunset", POSIXct.out=TRUE)

# calculate dawn & dusk times with local date/time
dawn<-crepuscule(stcalc@coords, dt_local, solarDep=12, direction="dawn", POSIXct.out=TRUE) #nautical dawn = 12 degrees for angle of sun below horizon
dawn #some are NA, some are not?
dusk<-crepuscule(stcalc, dt_local, solarDep=12, direction="dusk", POSIXct.out=TRUE)
dusk # some are NA, some are not? 
df$Sunrise<-sr$time
df$Sunset<-st$time
df$Dawn<-dawn$time 
df$Dusk<-dusk$time

# use sunrise/sunset/dawn/dusk to determine light levels; 
df$Light = ifelse(df$date.time.local < df$Dawn, "Night", ifelse(df$date.time.local < df$Sunrise, "Dawn", ifelse(df$date.time.local < df$Sunset, "Day", ifelse(df$date.time.local < df$Dusk, "Dusk", "Night"))))
df$Light = factor(df$Light)
df # here some of the light column are NA, some give a dawn/day/dusk/night calculation
```

Thank you in advance for any advice  ... what am I missing?

Comment: At 57 North Latitude at the start of July, you are pretty far north and close to the summer solstice.  It may be possible that it doesn't actually get dark at that time of the year.

Comment: I agree, but wouldn't it always be "dawn" or "dusk" and never "night" in that case?

Comment: Yes, I would agree that in those cases, it is just dusk (twilight) and never night.